# Issue with hibernate/Spring transaction management

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions

I am facing a problem with Spring Transaction management. I am using hibernate as ORM framework. And below is my spring for transaction management.

```
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
      <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>


  <bean id="abstractDao"
      class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean" abstract="true" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="transactionManager"/>
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
        <ref bean="transactionAttributeSource"/>
    </property>   
    <property name="postInterceptors">
      <list>
        <ref bean="finderIntroductionAdvisor"/>
      </list>
    </property>       
</bean>
   <bean id="abstractService"
      class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean" abstract="true" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="transactionManager"/>
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
        <ref bean="transactionAttributeSource"/>
    </property>   
</bean>
```

I am basically following genericDao approach as mentioned [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao/index.html) so My DaoObject are used to fetch the Domain objects  and service classes have DAO objects to maipulate them.

issue i am facing : i am querying a large dataset and loading the result in a list inside the service class. i have marked service class as @transactional(readonly ="true").

to handle some reuirement i have changed all the getters of boxed primitive to

```
  @Column(name = "students")
public Long getStudents() {
    if(students== null){
        return 0l;
    }
    return this.students;
}
```

whenever i load all the dataset via a named query. multiple update queries are fired subsequently to update the dataset. 
I debugged that and came to know that this is occuring because of transaction.commit. as hibernate is treating my entities as dirty.

is there a way i can avoid this .  i know Flushmode.never could be of help but in my application seesion object is not exposed so i do not have access to it. is there any other way or some mapping change which can help me ?

Comment: The only scenario when I've seen hibernate trying to issue updates or deletes after doing just a query, is when the mapping is wrong which makes hibernate think that certain elements were deleted or updated. I'm just mentioning this as there's a big chance that this is the underlying problem.

Comment: Could I suggest changing the title of the question?  Since SO is considered to be a reference for the future it's nice to have questions be browsable as well as searchable.

Comment: yeah Bill surely you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Xavi López's answer, another option is to separate persistent property handled by Hibernate from the transient property that conform to your requirement. For example, as follows:

```
@Column(name = "students")
public Long getStudentsInternal() {
    return students;
}

@Transient
public Long getStudents() {
    if (students == null) {
        return 0l;
    }
    return students;
}
```

You can also configure Hibernate to use fields instead of properties by moving annotations to them, it will solve your problem as well (note that the placement of annotations should be consitent for all fields of the entity, or you can use `@Access` to configure an exclusion):

```
@Column(name = "students")
private Long students;

public Long getStudents() {
    if (students == null) {
        return 0l;
    }
    return students;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with

`if(students== null){
        return 0l;
    }`

When Hibernate fetches your entities, they all have null value on the `students`field. At commit time, when checking if they are dirty, `getStudents()` returns 0, which is different from the value stored in the database. So, Hibernate sees them as dirty, and proceeds to the update.

If it is suitable to your requirement, changing the type of the `student`field to the primitive type `long` instead of `Long` would probably help. Note that this would lead to updating all `null`'s in that column to 0 in the long term.

Maybe you should handle that requirement somewhere else, and free the getter from that concern.

Comment: but that would throw Nullpointer as students in DB is null and  hibernate will try to set null to a primitive

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer.  Got bit by this one once and it's a lesson I won't soon forget.

Comment: @digitaljoel Neither will I. Embeddables with all fields `null` turning the whole embeddable into `null` got me entertained for days :) Anyway, I think [axtavt's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404075/issue-with-hibernate-spring-transaction-management/7404370#7404370) is the right solution.

Comment: Just to add, another possibility would be implementing a `PropertyAccessor`

Comment: alright, perhaps I should have said, "this is absolutely the correct diagnosis"  axtavt's answer does look good too.